# Java with Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase

Is there a way to use pure Java with Firebase? Meaning that we can communicate with Firebase using a driver without the android sdk or java rest api.
Like using sqlite with Java requires the JDBC driver

Comment: Isn't the sdk basically a driver for you? Of course you can talk to firebase directly if you manually implement all the APIs yourself, will not be fun though.

Comment: can you suggest me a way to use javafx with firebase??

Comment: Please ask a specific question about whatever difficulty you are having using firebase with javafx.

Comment: Perhaps use the [Java Firebase Admin SDK](https://randomprogrammingstuff.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/connect-to-google-firebase-using-admin-java-sdk-quick-start-tutorial/).